# How can I launch mods in Steam?

Tags: steam, mods, europa-universalis-3

I just downloaded the Devlet-i Ali Osman Alternate mod for EU3 Divine Wind, and in preference, set launch options to *-mod[daoalternet]* and have put the daoalternet folder and the daoalternet.mod file in the mod folder of EU3. When I press play, the mod doesn't run. Can anyone help?

Comment: Some mods may also require a set launch command, accessible by going into Properties and looking at Launch Options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out how for EU3; look in the EU3 folder for the EU3.EXE file and open it rather than the eu3game.exe file. After you open the EU3.EXE, look at the combobox at the bottom and press the mod you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing in the mod folder name under launch options for the game like this: `-game "foldernamehere"`